# Laravel: Paginating a query on a view MySQL Error 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I am trying to do a simple pagination of a query that uses a view:

```
DB::table('vw_myview')->paginate(50)
```

And get this error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from vw_myview)

Yet when I manually run the query, it works just fine:

```
mysql> select count(*) as aggregate from vw_myview;
+-----------+
| aggregate |
+-----------+
|       776 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.20 sec)
```

After searching around I found that I should just have to add a `GROUP BY` clause (just like the error says) and I have tried doing that with no luck:

```
DB::table('vw_myview')->groupBy('column_on_view')->paginate(50)
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'database_name.table_used_by_view.column_on_table' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from vw_myview group by `column_on_view`)

Okay lets try grouping by a column on one of the tables the view uses:

```
DB::table('vw_myview')->groupBy('table_used_by_view.column_on_table')->paginate(50)
```

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'database_name.table_used_by_view.column_on_table' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from vw_myview group by database_name.table_used_by_view.column_on_table)

So why does the query work when I run it manually but fails when run through Eloquent? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this article. http://programmingarehard.com/2013/11/10/eloquent_and_views.html/

Comment: @RutvijKothari I'm not sure that article helps me, it covers handling reading and writing when using a view. Am I missing something?

Comment: That should work as is... How is it handled in your view? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: @Serge That's all the code I really have heh. Its a pre-existing database and I haven't yet built out any Models or Controllers, just testing things in `routes/web.php`. I'm throwing those DB calls at a view that spits out a simple table. The only thing I modified was the names of the database, tables, and views because it is branded for my client.

Comment: You know, I am thinking your Mysql server has the sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY turned on... Can you check this... (from mysql ... select @@sql_mode;

If it is set, turn it off... and try your query again... I think it shall pass... Mysql 5.7xxx has this turned on by default now...

Comment: Wow that was it! Looking into it I found that it was enabled because I had "strict" mode enabled in my `config/database.php` file. Fantastic, thank you! If you want to add an answer I will give you the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, I am thinking your Mysql server has the sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY turned on... Can you check this... (from mysql ... select @@sql_mode; If it is set, turn it off... and try your query again... I think it shall pass... Mysql 5.7xxx has this turned on by default now...

Comment: In Laravel, you can disable this by editing `config/database.php` and setting 'strict' to `false` on your connection.