# Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

## SQL Error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of
>   GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is
>   illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: SELECT
>   sum(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount,
>   COALESCE(CONCAT(payment_mode.payment_name, '(', ROUND(
>   SUM(vehicles.total_amount)*100/Total.TotalAmount, 2),'%)'),0) as
>   Percent FROM `vehicles` LEFT OUTER join payment_mode ON
>   payment_mode.id = vehicles.pay_mode_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
>   SUM(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount, flag from vehicles) as
>   Total ON Total.flag=vehicles.flag WHERE vehicles.created_at >
>   '2020-03-25 00:01:01' and vehicles.created_at < '2020-03-25 23:59:59'
>   GROUP BY vehicles.pay_mode_id)

## SQL Query

```
SELECT sum(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount,
        COALESCE(CONCAT(payment_mode.payment_name, '(', ROUND( SUM(vehicles.total_amount)*100/Total.TotalAmount, 2),'%)'),0) as Percent
FROM `vehicles`
LEFT OUTER join payment_mode ON payment_mode.id = vehicles.pay_mode_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SUM(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount, flag from vehicles) as Total ON Total.flag=vehicles.flag
WHERE vehicles.created_at > '$today' and vehicles.created_at < '$todays'
GROUP BY vehicles.pay_mode_id
```

this is my code, even this code is working well on MySQL but when I put into Laravel its shows errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Paginating a query on a view MySQL Error 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044851/laravel-paginating-a-query-on-a-view-mysql-error-1140-mixing-of-group-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery `(SELECT SUM(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount, flag from vehicles) as Total` is wrong - add `GROUP BY flag` to it:

```
SELECT sum(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount,
        COALESCE(CONCAT(payment_mode.payment_name, '(', ROUND( SUM(vehicles.total_amount)*100/Total.TotalAmount, 2),'%)'),0) as Percent
FROM `vehicles`
LEFT OUTER join payment_mode ON payment_mode.id = vehicles.pay_mode_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vehicles.total_amount) as TotalAmount, flag 
                  from vehicles
                  GROUP BY flag ) as Total ON Total.flag=vehicles.flag
WHERE vehicles.created_at > '$today' and vehicles.created_at < '$todays'
GROUP BY vehicles.pay_mode_id
```

Comment: I tried which you said sir, but still, it is showing error.

Comment: @arunkumar Please add into the question text the DDLs of all tables used in the query (indexes, table options and columns not used in a query may be skipped). And specify MySQL version. We'll try...