# Laravel run complex query without disabling mysql strict mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have quite a complex query which is like:

```sql
SELECT 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN `closed_job_reports`.`job_report_id` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `CLOSED`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN `job_reports`.`id` IS NULL 
      AND `jobs`.`deadline` <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `OVERDUE`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN (
        `assigned_jobs`.`assigned_job_id` IS NULL 
        AND `pending_jobs`.`id` IS NOT NULL 
        AND `jobs`.`deadline` > NOW ()
      ) 
      OR (
        `assigned_jobs`.`assigned_job_id` IS NOT NULL 
        AND `jobs`.`deadline` > NOW () 
        AND `job_reports`.`id` IS NULL
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `PENDING`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN `closed_job_reports`.`job_report_id` IS NULL 
      AND `job_reports`.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `AWAITING_CLOSURE`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN (
        `job_reports`.`id` IS NULL 
        OR `assigned_jobs`.`assigned_job_id` IS NULL
      ) 
      AND (
        `jobs`.`deadline` > NOW ()
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `OPEN`, 
  COALESCE (
    COUNT (*), 
    0
  ) AS `TOTAL`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      `job_reports`.`distance_travelled`
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `distance_travelled`, 
  COALESCE (
    ROUND(
      SUM (
        CASE WHEN (
          `job_reports`.`id` IS NOT NULL 
          AND `jobs`.`job_category_id` = 2
        ) THEN ABS (
          TIMESTAMPDIFF (
            SECOND, `job_reports`.`end_time`, 
            `job_reports`.`start_time`
          )
        ) ELSE 0 END
      ) / 3600, 
      2
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `hours_worked`, 
  COALESCE (
    COUNT (`job_reports`.`id`), 
    0
  ) AS `num_reported_sites`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN `jobs`.`job_category_id` = 2 
      AND `job_reports`.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `pm_num_reported_jobs`, 
  COALESCE (
    SUM (
      CASE WHEN `jobs`.`job_category_id` = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ), 
    0
  ) AS `pm_num_jobs` 
FROM 
  `jobs` 
  INNER JOIN `job_categories` ON `job_categories`.`id` = `jobs`.`job_category_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `assigned_jobs` ON `jobs`.`id` = `assigned_jobs`.`job_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_reports` ON `assigned_jobs`.`assigned_job_id` = `job_reports`.`assigned_job_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `closed_job_reports` ON `job_reports`.`id` = `closed_job_reports`.`job_report_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `pending_jobs` ON `jobs`.`id` = `pending_jobs`.`new_job_id` 
WHERE
  `jobs`.`date_added` BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-02-17' 
-- GROUP BY
--   `closed_job_reports`.`job_report_id`, `job_reports`.`id`, `assigned_jobs`.`assigned_job_id`, `pending_jobs`.`id`,  `closed_job_reports`.`job_report_id`, `job_reports`.`id`, `assigned_jobs`.`assigned_job_id`
ORDER BY 
  `jobs`.`id` DESC
```

I can easily run it from PhpMyAdmin and get what I want like what is shown below:

[image]

but when running from laravel with the DB::select method, I get a syntax error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of
> GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is
> illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: SELECT
> ...

I have a lot of such queries that I would be running. I checked this post:
[Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843390/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1140-mixing-of-group-columns-min-max-coun)

but mine seems to be a little more complicated owing to the fact that I have to query from several related tables. I have seen other people recommend **disabling mysql strict mode**, but I don't want to do that.

I know some of you might have encountered this issue with complicated queries. Please what steps or techniques you use in resolving some of these issues? Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that is really complex. Maybe you can use raw expressions https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Check if mysql strict mode is enabled in config/databases. If so, disable it

Comment: @IGP
I don't want to disable mysql strict mode

Comment: Two options: disable mysql strict mode, potentially on a separate connection in the config used explicitly for these kinds of queries; or create a view for each of these types of queries on the DB then query the view as if it were a table.

Comment: Okay @SEoF, based on the kind of query I want, I think I would have to create multiple views. Also, I may have to do this without creating a migration so that I assume it already exists. I hope this is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. so you've got a really complex query like mine? Well, I found out I did not need a view from the database because it was unnecessary in my case.

First, I had to break down my query into smaller parts and one at a time. This was after I was pointed to the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions

I started with the main table from the original query - jobs and proceeded to adding the joins to the query.

The grouping of the data was the most complicated part. That was what I had problems with. So after breaking down the query, I had to change what I was using for the original grouping of data. Grouping the data into job category name (or job category id) made it simpler.

In the end, the displayed results I was getting looked much better.

Here is a code to illustrate.
**I have made some modifications to the original queries but still maintaining the joins that I needed**.

```
$users = DB::table('jobs')
                    ->select(DB::raw(
                        
                        'job_categories.category_name, COUNT(jobs.id) as jobs_count, COUNT(assigned_jobs.assigned_job_id) AS assigned_jobs_count, 

                        COUNT(recurring_jobs.job_id) AS recurring_jobs_count,

                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN 
                            assigned_jobs.assigned_job_id IS NULL 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END
                        ), 0) AS unassigned_jobs_count,

                        COUNT(job_reports.id) AS reported_jobs_count,

                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN job_reports.id IS NULL
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END
                        ), 0) AS unreported_jobs_count,
                        
                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN closed_job_reports.job_report_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END
                        ), 0) AS closed_jobs_count,

                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN job_reports.id IS NOT NULL AND closed_job_reports.job_report_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                            END
                        ), 0) AS reported_unclosed_jobs_count,

                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN 
                                (job_reports.id IS NULL AND jobs.deadline > NOW() AND assigned_jobs.assigned_job_id IS NULL)
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END
                        ), 0) AS opened_only_jobs_count,

                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN 
                                job_reports.id IS NULL AND jobs.deadline > NOW() AND assigned_jobs.assigned_job_id IS NOT NULL OR 

                                (job_reports.id IS NULL AND jobs.deadline > NOW() AND pending_jobs.id IS NOT NULL)

                            THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END
                        ),0) AS pending_jobs_count,
                        
                        COALESCE(SUM(
                            CASE WHEN job_reports.id IS NULL AND jobs.deadline <= NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END
                        ), 0) AS overdue_jobs_count
                        
                        '                    
                    ))
                    ->groupBy('job_categories.category_name')
                    ->join('job_categories', 'job_categories.id', '=', 'jobs.job_category_id')
                    ->leftJoin('assigned_jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'assigned_jobs.job_id')
                    ->leftJoin('pending_jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'pending_jobs.new_job_id')
                    ->leftJoin('job_reports', 'job_reports.assigned_job_id', '=', 'assigned_jobs.assigned_job_id')
                    ->leftJoin('closed_job_reports', 'closed_job_reports.job_report_id', '=', 'job_reports.id')
                    ->leftJoin('recurring_jobs', 'recurring_jobs.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
                    ->get();
```

I hope this helps someone to troubleshoot their issues with the error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

when using laravel or other similar framework...